# Modular arthimetic congruent four distinct values

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What are the four distinct values which are congruent to 6 when the base is 12?

we got 1,and 4 so far but no the other two numbers

Comment: There is only one congruence class which contains $6$ modulo $12$.  Is there some other information to work with here?

Comment: no, that is all the question gave us

Comment: Is the question you asked exactly what the question gave you? You have maybe misunderstood something.

Comment: that is the question right out of the workout! we got 6,and 18! 1 and 4 didn't work

Comment: Assuming that $1$ and $4$ are solutions to some problem which involves moduli $6$ and $12$, then it is reasonable to assume that their negatives are also solutions, i.e., $2,5$ modulo $6$ or $8,11$ modulo $12$.  If $12$ is used as the *number base* and "congruence" is used in a different way, then perhaps another problem from the same set of questions would help clarify the intent.

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinite number:
6+12n
for all integers n.

Are you sure that is question
you meant to ask?
When you say "base" what do tou mean?
Like decimal?